# Typescript selection box object might possibly be undefined

Tags: typescript

I have a selection box and an array of tabs. I'm getting an error that it might be possibly undefined.

here are the tabs ( might be mutable in future) :

```
const tabs = [
  { name: "1 tab",  current: true },
  { name: "2 tab",  current: false },
  { name: "3 tab",  current: false },
];
```

here is the selection part:

```
 <label htmlFor="question-tabs" className="sr-only">
        Select a tab
      </label>
      <select
        id="question-tabs"
        className="block w-full"
        defaultValue={tabs.find((tab) => tab.current).name}
      >
        {tabs.map((tab) => (
          <option key={tab.name}>{tab.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
```

I'm having some issue with this line:

```
defaultValue={tabs.find((tab) => tab.current).name
```

the error says that the object might be possibly undefined.
How can I check to see if it is undefined, and if so just put some default text?

I've tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
defaultValue={tabs ? tabs.find((tab) => tab.current).name : ''}
```

Comment: You need to check if tabs.find((tab) => tab.current) returns undefined or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns `undefined` if `tabs` doesn't contain `tab`.
Using Optional Chaining (`?.`) and the Nullish Coalescing Operator (`??`), you can return a default value like so:

```
tabs.find((tab) => tab.current)?.name ?? "default"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use optional chaining operator (`?.`):

```
defaultValue={tabs.find((tab) => tab.current)?.name}
```

Or how about simply just using the first element:

```
defaultValue={tabs[0].name}
```

If you also want to provide a default, you can use the null coalescing operator (`??`)

```
defaultValue={tabs.find((tab) => tab.current)?.name ?? "--"}
```